# Weird behaviour while using Data Annotation regular expression attribute

Tags: .net, regex

I need to write a model object validation using data annotation in ASP.NET MVC 4. The requirement is to allow all alphabets, numbers and the below characters.

```
@'!&(){}:;,[].+?/-
```

All other special chars should be a validation error.
I have the below code

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9 @'!&(){}:;,\[\].+?/-]+", ErrorMessage = NameIsNotValid)] 
public string Name { get; set; }
```

This code does not throw validation exception for a String "TEST NAME |||"

But if I modify the code as

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9 '!&(){}:;,\[\].+?/-]+", ErrorMessage = NameIsNotValid)] 
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

by removing one char (@ or -)  from the regular expression validation happens properly. Again I add the char back, validation error is not thrown

Now I am stuck, dunno what to do.. Please advice

Comment: `@` has no special meaning in regex, so it's weird, but I think that you need `$` at the end of the expression

Comment: I modified the code to [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9 @'!&(){}:;,\[\].+?/-]+)$", ErrorMessage = NameIsNotValid)] ..still no luck

Comment: Try escaping the @ with a backslash

Comment: tried adding a backslash infront of @..no luck..its not only with @, instead of @ if I remove - it works fine.. if I remove any char it works fine.. dunno its as though there is a size restriction or something

Answer (score 0):

I can only test this in normal c#, and I see two problems with your regex:

1. You don't use an end anchor `$`, so your validation should always be true as soon as the name starts with a valid character.
2. `a-zA-Z` are only ASCII letters. I would replace this with the [Unicode character property](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) `\p{L}`, which will match any letter in any language.

So, try

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[\p{L}0-9 @'!&(){}:;,\[\].+?/-]+$", ErrorMessage = NameIsNotValid)] 
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still not working with your changes.I have also noticed that in normal c# code its working fine. This is failing only in the Data Annotations. I am suspecting some kind of a bug in the .Net data annotations RegularExpression attribute

Comment: @Sri did you get any solution? i'm finding answer for this too